# Update large number of rows in Oracle

Tags: c#, oracle, ado.net

I have this situation and I'm trying to think of the best way to solve it. I have a database, say DB-A, with a table T-A that has 2 fields - OID and PID. This table has close to 1million rows. Now due to some other issue, the PIDs of most of the rows were incorrectly set to 0 and this was found only after a couple of days.

I have a backup from 2 days back, say DB-B, and I'm thinking of updating DB-A with matching entries from DB-B. So what would be the best way to do this ? I have this in mind:

1. Create a .NET app that gets rows from DB-B and updates matching ones in DB-A. Not sure if this will work because of the large no of rows. Maybe will need individual commits under a scoped transaction.

   2. Create a .NET to generate an Oracle SQLloader file from DB-B and load into DB-A

Your thoughts are greatly appreciated...

thanks
Sunit

Answer (score 1):

If you can build a dblink from DB-A to DB-B then you could execute a simple update from DB-A:

```
UPDATE (SELECT ta.pid ta_pid, tb.pid tb_pid
          FROM ta ta
          JOIN ta@backup tb ON (ta.oid = tb.oid))
   SET ta_pid = tb_pid;
```

It will work if OID is a primary key.

Comment: I'd also consider doing a rename of the table in the backup database, export it and import it into the current database with the new name. Then do the update within the same DB and drop the backup table.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you load the backup as (e.g.) T-B and do a query like:

```
UPDATE T-A, T-B SET T-A.pid = T-B.pid WHERE T-A.oid = T-B.oid
```

Excuse my MySQL-ese SQL, but in theory it shoulw work.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a 1-1 relation among DBA.TA and DBB.TB, first I would delete DBA.TA and then change Asmodon's answer UPDATE's to INSERT's.

If it's not possible I would disable/delete every constraint/index on DBA.TA, do the updates and then reenable/create the constraints/indexes.

Regards.

Answer (score -2):

There may be a built in tool for this, but if it were me, I would probably use DB-B to generate a list of `update` statements and run them as a script in DB-A.

Something like:

```
select 'update T-A set PID = ' || PID || ' where OID = ' || OID || ';' from T-A
```

(This assumes that OID is your primary key.  Since you have a large number of rows you might have to break it into multiple scripts.  Someone else may be able to offer a more elegant solution.)

Comment: Forgot to mention that OID is of type RAW16.

Comment: And a million unique updates will do horrible things to your database (ie lots of parsing overhead).